# Proving a recursive series convergence: $a_{n+1}={2a_n^2 \over a_n^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am stuck with this example, with no way out at the moment:
I need to prove that the following series has a limit, and to find it:
$$a_0=\alpha, (\alpha \in  \Bbb R)$$
$$a_{n+1}={2a_n^2 \over a_n^2+1}$$
So far I concluded that $a_n$ is between: $0\le a_n \le 2$:
$$a_{n+1}={2a_n^2 \over a_n^2+1}\le{2a_n^2 \over a_n^2}=2$$
I have no idea how to proceed. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline:** You can show the sequence is monotone: you've shown it is bounded, so you'll get convergence.

**In detail:**
$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{a_n^2}{a_n^2 + 1}-a_n = a_n\left(\frac{a_n-a_n^2-1}{a_n^2 + 1}\right)=-a_n\left(\frac{a_n^2-a_n+1}{a_n^2 + 1}\right)$$
Now, you showed that $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, and since $X^2-X+1$ has no real roots you have $a_{n+1} - a_n \leq 0$ for all $n$. I.e., $(a_n)_n$ is a non-increasing sequence, bounded below: it converges.

Finally, note that the limit $\ell$ of the sequence must satisfy, by continuity,
$$
\ell = \frac{2\ell^2}{\ell^2+1}.
$$
Solving this should show that the limit can only be one of two values: depending on $\alpha$, you can then conclude on what $\ell$ is.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer.** $a_n\to 1$ for $\lvert a\rvert \ge 1$, while $a_n\to 0$ for $\lvert a\rvert <1$. Observe that, if $a_n>1$, then $a_n>a_{n+1}>1$,
while, if $0< a_n<1$, then $a_n>a_{n+1}>0$. Hence in every case the sequence converges.